# Decryption of message in IBE without random oracle using bilinear pairing registration?

Tags: pairings, identity-based-encryption

I find the following IBE scheme from the videos posted and i don't understand the decryption algorithm, will any one please elaborate  the  6th step

scheme

1. Setup($\lambda$)  :     $(\mathbb{G}, \mathbb{G}_T, g, P)$   <-- GenBilgroup($\lambda$)

   $\alpha\leftarrow_R\mathbb{F}_p$
2. Public Parameters :   $pp = [ g , y = g^\alpha  , g_1, h ] \in \mathbb{G}$
3. Master secret : $mk = g_1^\alpha $
4. Keygeneration:  $k(mk,id)$: $d_1= mk\cdot(Y^{id\cdot h})^r, d_2 = g^r $
   where   $r\leftarrow_R\mathbb{F}_p $
5. Encryption: $E(pp,id,m)$ :  $c_1 = g^s, c_2=(Y^{id\cdot h})^s, c_3=m\cdot e(y, g_1)^s$
6. Decryption: $e(c_1,d_1)/e(c_2,d_2)$ will give $e(y,g_1)^s$  How?
                and $m$ is obtained by dividing $c_3$ by that value.

Comment: You can use MathML / [Tex](http://tex.stackexchange.com) on this site.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether it is correct

$$e(c_1,d_1) = e(g^s, mk\cdot(y^{id\cdot h})^r)$$

$$=e(g^s,mk)\cdot e(g^s, (y^{id\cdot h})^r)$$

$$= e(g^s , g_1^\alpha ) \cdot e(g^r , (y^{id\cdot h})^s)$$

$$= e(y , g_1^\alpha ) \cdot e(g^r , (y^{id\cdot h})^s)$$

$$e(c_2,d_2)  = e((Y^{id\cdot h})^s , g^r)$$

$$= e((Y^{id\cdot h})^s , g^r)$$

therefore $e(c_1,d_1)/e(c_2,d_2) =  e(y , g_1^\alpha )$

Comment: Yes, of course it's correct. A straitforward calculation using the bilinearity of e, shows that dividing $c_3$ by $e(y,g_1^\alpha)$ allows to recover m.  I confirm.

Comment: @manju If the answer fits, you might want to *“accept”* it… thanks.